# PHP, Includue Files

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

I have a simple question:
When I autoload "spl_autoload_register()" all files / classes in each file, does it have influence on the Servers performance? or the performance of the code?

e.G. Main File:

```
<?php

include "xxx"
include "YYY"      <- Class1{}
include "ZZZ"

$callClass = new Class1();
$callClass->function();
?>
```

Does my code process all include Files or just the needed?

Answer (score 0):

PHP will process all of the included files, not just the ones that are used.

From the docs:

> The include statement includes and evaluates the specified file.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: sure, I see in debug mode. Anyway, my question was actually, if there is server performance lost, if I include too many files in different files, which  arent acutally needed/used (eg. include file).